# Defining a wrapper function in glmulti

Tags: r

I am new to R scripting and I would like to run glmulti with a wrapper function for a negative binomial family with offset.
I would like advice on the following code since I am getting an error message. Variables a,b and c are factors and d a covariate. Variable e is used as an offset.

```
glmnb.glmulti <- function(formula, data, offset, ...)
  glm.nb(formula, offset=offset, data=data, ...)

selection<- glmulti(y~ a + b + c + d,level=2, 
fitfunction=glmnb.glmulti, offset=log(e), crit="aic")

Initialization...
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = formula, data = data, offset = offset,  : 
  invalid type (closure) for variable '(offset)'
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot! I also tried the following and it also worked

eqt <- as.formula(y~ a + b + c + d)

glmnb <- function(formula, data, weights, ...)
  glm.nb(formula, data=data, weights=offset(log(e)), ...)

selection <- glmulti(eqt, data=data, fitfunction=glmnb,  crit = "aic")